# NavigationDrawer fails if compiled with play-services

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-coordinatorlayout, android-multidex

I was able to compile and run wihtout any problem, a NavigationDrawer example.

Next, I included a module which in turn include google play-services library (This module 'map' is tested and used in another proyect and is working perfectly)

But when I add this module to the build.gradle as a dependency, `(compile proyect (':map'))`, the build fail.

The message is:

> "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536"

I understood this error happnes because the number of method exceeds the maximum of 64K. So I use the 'multiDexEnabled true' option.

Now it compiles perfect, BUT runnning in debug mode, it throws a run time exception, at the moment it is trying to load the `CoordinatorLayout` layout

**This is what the console throws**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.simplifiedcoding.navigationdrawerexample/net.simplifiedcoding.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at net.simplifiedcoding.navigationdrawerexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
```

I also try to limit the declaration of the libraris to only what I intend to use, replacing

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

with

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:+'
```

Same problem. It is build, but failed when loading the Coordinator Layout.

**The question is:**

Is it possible to run a NavigationDrawer together with a project that includes the play-services library, together with the multiDexEnabled option set (I need to set this option  anyway, because i have a lot of method in the root project)

Hope it is clear enough

**This is the build.grade of the NavigationDrawer:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "net.simplifiedcoding.navigationdrawerexample"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
        compile project (':map')
    }
```

**and this is the build.gradle of the map project include as dependency of the NavigationDrawer**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:24'
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25

        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:+'
    }
```

Comment: Never ever use `+` as the version number!

Comment: You have your errors mixed up. `CoordinatorLayout` has nothing to do with the other message. Make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to cricket_007's comment, you may want to check this caution given in [Adding Support Libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#add-library):

> Using dynamic dependencies (for example, `palette-v7:23.0.+`) can cause unexpected version updates and regression incompatibilities. We recommend that you explicitly specify a library version (for example, `palette-v7:25.2.0`).

Furthermore, check used versions. As noted in [Manifest Declaration Changes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#manifest)

> If you are including several support libraries, the minimum SDK version must be the highest version required by any of the specified libraries. For example, if your app includes both the [v14 Preference Support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v14-preference) and the [v17 Leanback library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v17-leanback), your minimum SDK version must be 17 or higher.

Lastly, you may want to also check this [article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Design-Support-Library) for additional insights about Design Support Library.

Comment: I declare minimum SDK to 18 and now is working. Thank you very much!